# stream vimeo file through server without revealing src

Tags: php, codeigniter, video-streaming, embed, vimeo

I'm using a LAMP stack with CodeIgniter to "power" a site. I'm trying to find a way to stream/embed a video that's hosted on Vimeo but without revealing the vimeo source of the file. My purpose is to restrict access to certain users. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found my own possible answer, but I'm not accepting my own answer just yet, in case anyone has a better idea.

Apparently, my idea of restricting access to the Vimeo Video URL via PHP/CodeIgniter is not feasible. However, Vimeo provides Plus and PRO account with the ability to limit access to the videos so that they are only embedabble on a specific set of domains. Here's a fuller discussion on their forums:
http://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:31238

They also provide oEmbed and other APIs:
https://developer.vimeo.com/apis

So, in effect, I can achieve my goal by:

1. Restricting the video to only be embed-able on my domain
2. Embedding the video inside CodeIgniter, using my own access restrictions.

This would appear to prevent users from being able to just type in the vimeo video url and bypass my access controls.

Comment: we have a similar issue at hand....vimeo uses akamai cdn and if you look at the video src in any html5 browser you get the URL on the cdn

there is no restriction whatsoever with that link...dumbstruck !

Comment: Ironically, I now work at an online video company. Some possible approaches here would be to use Amazon S3 with signed urls. Another approach would be to ditch vimeo and use Brightcove (my employer) for ingestion and DRM, or one of our many competitors. I hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: You could also use Zencoder (also my employer) to transcode your videos on the backend (especially if these are user generated rather than employee generated videos), store the videos in S3, and write some access control logic in the language/framework of your choice to restrict access to videos in the S3 bucket.